# How to organize unit testing of a library project in Xcode?

Tags: unit-testing, xcode, project-organization

I'm not yet a fan of integrated development environments, but I'm trying to overcome my prejudices and learn Xcode.  (Eclipse/CDT is next; I couldn't get that to work for me either when I tried last year, but that's a separate issue.)

I am writing some new code in a new project that will become (part of) a small library.  I want to unit test it, too.  How do I explain to Xcode that I'm building a (shared) library, but I also want to use it in a test program, compiled from separate source that won't be in the shared library?

Source code:

- atom.c
- atom.h
- test-atom.c

Produced files:

- libatom.dylib
- test-atom

I've got `atom.c` and `atom.h` compiled into the library.  I'm just not sure how to organize things so that I can also build `test-atom` to link with the library.
I'm assuming that when I've got that sorted, adding the library for the test support code that test-atom.c would be relatively straight-forward - even though it isn't under Xcode control yet.

FWIW, I primarily work in C rather than Objective C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need two targets in your project; a target in Xcode produces a *product* which is a library, executable, or some other output.

Thus you'd have a target to produce `libatom.dylib`, which I suspect you've already set up, and another command-line executable target to produce the `test-atom` executable for you to run to test your library.

Once you've added the `test-atom` target, you should Get Info on `test-atom.c` and remove its *membership* from the `libatom.dylib` target, and add it as a member of your new `test-atom` target.  The target membership of a file is what determines whether building a target will try to compile/copy/link that file.  (What the target does with the file depends on what build phase it gets added to when it's made a member.)

You should also Get Info on the `libatom.dylib` entry in your Products group, and make *that* a member of the `test-atom` target as well.  That will cause the `test-atom` executable to link against `libatom.dylib`.

Finally, Get Info on the `test-atom` target (not the product) and in the General tab, add a *dependency* on the `libatom.dylib` target.  This will ensure that building the `test-atom` target will always first build the `libatom.dylib` target.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: See [Automated Unit Testing with Xcode 3 and Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/mac/articles/tools/unittestingwithxcode3.html) (a more recent version of the article I originally linked to, as pointed to in a comment below). Also see [What is the best way to unit test Objective-C code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33207/what-is-the-best-way-to-unit-test-objective-c-code) While you clearly aren't using Obj-C yet, the basics of setting up new targets will be the same for C code, and the OCUnit specific stuff is very representative of how unit testing works in an IDE.

Comment: Please don't point people to "Test Driving Your Code With OCUnit" - it's obsolete, and has been grossly out of date since a couple months after it was published. For one thing, it tells people to download OCUnit, but OCUnit has been included with Xcode since WWDC 2005 when Xcode 2.1 was released. Please point people to "Automated Unit Testing with Xcode 3 and Objective-C" http://developer.apple.com/mac/articles/tools/unittestingwithxcode3.html instead.