# How can I run "test code" in Xcode and not have the test-related code in the release build?

Tags: testing, xcode4

**Fixed: My database was empty**. I had code that overwrote my existing (filled) db. Nothing to see here :)

I have 3 "test" classes that runs a test on my app. Part of the app's function is parsing HTML, so I have a database of markup code to test against. I don't want these 3 test classes and the markup code database included in my released code. How can I set up Xcode to make this happen?

I am also running unit tests, so I have put in a test method to hook into my test classes, but the following if statement does not evaluate to true:

```
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
```

The first thing that come to mind is whether libsqlite3.0.dylib and the .sqlite was copied over (it was), further more the statement below that comes before this line **does evaluate to true**:

```
if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK
```

So I can assume(?) that the sqlite db and dylib are in place.

Keeping in mind that the code was copied exactly from a known working copy, I worked back over  the following:

- I have verified that the database and sql variables are not nil before the line in question are not nil
- I have assigned the dylib, .sqlite, and test classes targets to all targets (mostly because I am learning about how targets work in general)
- Using breakpoints I verified that the test method on my Xcode-created test case class is being called

I am wondering if it a setting I am missing, or if it is just not supported in the SenTestingKit framework. Is it possible to hook in test classes in this manner?

Comment: Describe "not working" for using the test classes from unit tests.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319906/how-to-organize-unit-testing-of-a-library-project-in-xcode