# What is a good tutorial for getting started with iPhone unit testing using OCUnit?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, unit-testing, ocunit

I am trying to get OCUnit to do anything on my project, but I am failing :-(
Is there any good tutorial out there to get it work? Everything I find tells something different and they are all pretty complicated ...

What I tried is e.g.

1. set up a Unit Testing Target
2. add my Target as dependency
3. add a xxTest.m to my unit target and write a testcase like:

code:

```
#import <SenTestingKit/SenTestingKit.h>

@interface XTest : SenTestCase {
}
@end

@implementation XTest
- (void)testAuthentication {
 STFail(@"fail");
}
```

@end

The result is, a build success ... What do I have to do to get unit testing working ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I demonstrate the setup of unit tests, along with the new UI Automation interface testing instrument, in the video for the "Testing" class session in my iPhone development class on [iTunes U](https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/advanced-iphone-development-fall-2010/id407243028).  The video for the "Unit testing" session from [last semester's class](https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/advanced-iphone-development-spring-2010/id407243032) also delves into this in detail.

My course notes for unit testing from last semesters session can be found [here](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/Spring2010CourseNotes/unit%20testing.html).  I created a small sample application illustrating the use of unit tests, with the source code available for download from [here](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/UnitTestExample.zip).

I also highly recommend [Graham Lee's course on test-driven development for Cocoa](http://ideveloper.tv/video/unittestingcourse.html) on iDeveloper.tv. You do have to pay for those videos, but they are well worth the cost for the quality of the material presented there. I picked up a lot of techniques from watching them.

Comment: Thanks for your samples - they are great !

Comment: +1 for your screencast, and a moral +1 for referencing Graham's screencast. They are good.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked before:  [What is the best way to unit test Objective-C code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33207/what-is-the-best-way-to-unit-test-objective-c-code)

All of the information you need can be found here:  http://developer.apple.com/tools/unittest.html

Google provides a library of useful code for iPhone developers which also includes an alternative testing framework.  Some like it better than the OCUnit that is included with Xcode:  http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/wiki/iPhoneUnitTesting

Comment: That doesn't quite answer my questions - I need a tutorial how to get OCUnit for iPhone working - which it does not do for me :-(

Comment: @RRZ Europe - I'd recommend reading Chris Hanson's articles, which are linked to in the accepted answer on that question.  They provide a pretty detailed look at unit testing for Mac and iPhone.

Comment: I also found my problem by looking at your sample - I had set the target to Device, then the build will succeed, when I set it to Simulator, the STFail, etc will correctly cause the tests to fail !